# How click in a button above another button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a big button and a small button above the big button. What I want is: when the user click on the small button, activate his click event and not the click event from the big button. Thanks!

EDIT: I have a form with 2 System.Windows.Forms.Button. Visual Studio 2017.

A image to ilustrate:

[image]

EDIT²: The smllButton starts invisible!
MouseEnter event of bigButton: `smallButton.Visible = true`
MouseLeave event of bigButton: `smllButton.visible = false`

Comment: I think we need more information than you've given.

Comment: Have you tried Bring to front in the designer, or BringToFront() in your code? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351054/winform-ui-components-layer-order

Comment: The first thing that I tried

Comment: You could also go this route https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134352/how-to-create-a-clickable-irregularly-shaped-region

Comment: I just created a WinForms project, added a big button with a click handler, added a small button on top of it with a different click handler, and it behaves exactly as you desire.  So there's something more to this that you're not saying.

Comment: Of couse!! I forget to say that the small button is `Visible = false` and on the MouseEnter event of the big button I wrote: `smallButton.Visible = true`. That's it! Now you have all information. Sorry for the lack of attention...

Comment: also on MouseLeave event of the big button I wrote: `smallButton.Visible = false`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `MouseDown` event on the big button to send a click to the little button:

```
private void bigButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (littleButton.Bounds.Contains(littleButton.Parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))) {
        littleButton_Click(littleButton, EventArgs.Empty);
        return;
    }

    // Any code needed for MouseDown actually on big button goes here:
}
```

Note this makes it possible to drag the mouse from the little button to the big button and click both. You could move the big button's click code to this method instead.

An alternative would be to use only one button, change its appearance on `MouseEnter`, and use mouse X/Y to figure out which part of the button was clicked.