# Can I make The Shape of Form linear on C#?

Tags: c#

is there a way to make form shape linear
i I could make it as circle 
i used a GraphicsPath

```
       GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 150);
        path.AddEllipse(rec);
        this.Region = new Region(path);
```

but when i try to make it as line i try this code

```
         GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddLine(0,0,200,200);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(200, 200);
        this.Region = new Region(path);
```

but Nothing happened the form looks like disappear
So Can Someone help me please

Comment: How wide is your line? Zero. Hmmm ...

Comment: how i can change it's wide ?

Comment: Use a polygon. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137794/224370 for example.

Comment: I just need one line

Comment: `path.Widen(Pens.Black);` or set an arbitrary width `path.Widen(new Pen(Color.Black, 5));`