# How to define a free-shaped region?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics, region

I have a freehand shape, drawn on a PictureBox in a Windows Form. For example:

[image]

Now I need to determine whether a given point belongs to the shape.

As I know, I should have to make a Region object, then call its IsVisible() member function to find out the answer. I know how to do it on a region made by rectangles, arcs, circles, and so on, but my shape is free-hand, and I don't know how to set up a free-hand region.

Also, I have read the [How to create a clickable irregularly-shaped region in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134352/how-to-create-a-clickable-irregularly-shaped-region-in-c-sharp), which is so useful, but I didn't grasp the point because I'm a newbie.

If this is a duplicate question, please note me to delete my question, though I have done my best to find out a solution, but I was out of luck.

P.N.: Thanks to TaW for his/her helpful and accepted answer.

Comment: _it makes no help_ But it should!! Do look into `GraphicsPath` which should do what you need.. Forget about Regions, which are mostly needed for a) set operations or b) clipping control surfaces. Also: What is an 'Imagebox'? A `PictureBox` maybe? Alsway use the correct names!! ((Btw you could also create a Region from a GraphicsPath but this will not be necessary as GP has functions to determine if a point is inside or even on the GP path))

Comment: @TaW Thank you so much for the corrections. I made that corrections. Thanks again :)

Comment: perhaps the difficulty you're having is how to obtain a `GraphicsPath` from a picture that has already been drawn, and is now a `Bitmap` (tracing). If your users draw the shape, record the points as they draw, then there is no need to trace from bitmap.

Comment: @dlatikay Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_transperancy.php
maybe it can help you